# Why doesn't the VirtualBox address match the container address?

Tags: node.js, docker, kitematic

I made a Node app and deployed it in a Docker container. I then used `ipconfig` to get the address of the VirtualBox network (`192.168.99.1`). I was able to view the application at this address in my browser. I then made some changes to the app and restarted the container with the new image, and it didn't work. I reverted the changes and redeployed again, and it *still* didn't work.

I did some Googling and found out about Kitematic and used it to determine that the app was at `192.168.99.100`. How is it that using the VirtualBox IP address worked the first time but not the second time?